# How to find a problem on a Non working Yamaha SPX90 (Pro audio) effects unit

Tags: pcb, audio, repair

I have an electronic processor unit namely an SPX90 (a 19" pro audio effects unit made circa 1987). I'm a home studio producer and have owned it from new from 1987, but it died a few years ago. Now thanks to this SE, I'd like to find out how I might be able to fix it myself with your advice!

I have a multi-meter (M/M), but although I'm a pretty dab hand with home recording studio & home DIY. Using my multi-meter, I'd like to try to find out what has failed on the unit (obviously without the mains connected!). The Yamaha SPX90 was renowned for the internal power supply failing and I have an in-clinging it is this as the frontpanel power switch became very temperamental when last used (about 5 years ago) but it is a great classic unit and I really don't want it to go the tip as I could get another 10 years out of it, even though I have many other pro effects that superceed it.

I'm not sure where to start, could anyone give me some advice on what I need to do and what I'm looking for with the M/M, I'm really keen for this to be my first electronics project (-:

Comment: I would toss it and find a used 990.  The 90s sounded horrible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should search the web and find circuits or service manuals for it.

At the very minimum, you might be able to ascertain that there are dc voltages coming from the power supplies but, it requires a certain level of technical knowledge to understand the components you are seeing on the circuit boards or you may probe your multimeter in the wrong places and make invalid conclusions.

Make sure you are using DC voltage measurements and your probe wires are NOT connected to the amp measurement sockets. Try and determine if there is an obvious ground/0V point and measure relative to that. For an absolute guess I'd be expecting to see +12 volts and -12 volts on certain points but, this could easily be +/-5V or +/-15V.

Look for voltage regulator chips like ones marked with 7805, 7905, 7812, 7912, 7815, 7915 - these are linear voltage regulators that may have suffered - also inspect the big tubular things we call capacitors - quite often these components can fail and they sometimes show signs of deterioration by bulging or leaking goo from the internals. Also look at the copper on the circuit board to see if there are any scorched areas. Look for scorched components too - quite often resistors will age and eventually fail if they are subjected to continuous moderate-to-high powers.

Answer (score 2):

I concur with the approach suggested by Andy aka. The service manual is available at http://elektrotanya.com/yamaha_spx90_sm.pdf/download.html (the 'Get Manual' link under the image).

Looking at this, it seems as though the power supplies are on a separate PCB, so the voltages on the various rails may well be straightforward to measure at the point they are brought out on the connector to the main board. Looks as though the power supplies are +/-18V and +5V. The power supplies are switch-mode, so there probably won't be any 78xx/79xx series voltage regulators to look for, but failed capacitors are a likely candidate if the power supply has failed.

You mentioned that the front panel switch was very temperamental when the unit was last used; worth checking that the problem is not simply a faulty switch or loose connector!

Comment: Thank you all guys for the time spent replying, the post will probably be closed, but you all gave me positive comments, good karma to you all anyway! I will see if I can do anything with it, or try a local service guy local.